# Generating report for 30 day interval, daily totals

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have the below query which is meant to calculate CSR call metrics and totals per day. The way I run it now for the daily report is to group by extension and place now() and curdate() values in the date and time columns. However, I've now been tasked with modifying this to get a one-time report of daily totals per the 15 CSRs in the last 30 days, so take what it's doing now but gather it for the last 30 days.

After running the below query and selecting * from the ambitionLog30Days table, I have 354 rows which is right for the day count given weekends and absences. However, the totals are not right. For the sum columns below, it returns 1 or 0 so it is essentially only showing one call per CSR per day instead of totals.

Here's the query:

```
    Insert into test.ambitionLog30Days(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,
       Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, 
       Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report,Date_of_report  )  
    SELECT 
        c.extension 
       ,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID 
       , sum(Duration)  
       , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) 
       , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) 
       , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) 
       , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) 
       , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) + sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0))   as total_calls 
       , b.ts
       , b.ts 
    FROM cdrdb.session a
    INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
        ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
    INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c
        ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
        WHERE b.ts BETWEEN curdate() - interval 30 day and curdate()
    AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
    group by c.extension,b.ts
    ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds =values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), 
       Total_Talk_Time_minutes =values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes), 
       Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound), 
       Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound), 
       Missed_calls = values(Missed_calls), 
       Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls),
       Time_of_report = values(Time_of_report);
```

Session table columns:

```
    RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID  bigint(20)  YES
```

callsummary table columns:

```
    NOTABLECALLID   bigint(20)  YES UNI     
    STARTTIME   datetime    YES MUL     
    ENDTIME datetime    YES MUL     
    DURATION    int(11) YES MUL     
    ANSWERED    smallint(6) YES         
    ts  timestamp   NO  MUL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    firstcallid bigint(20)  YES
```

mxuser table columns:

```
    EXTENSIONID bigint(20)  NO  PRI 0   
    USERID  bigint(20)  YES MUL     
    ISLAST  smallint(6) YES         
    FIRSTNAME   varchar(32) YES         
    LASTNAME    varchar(32) YES         
    USERPROFILENAME varchar(32) YES MUL     
    EXTENSION   varchar(8)  NO          
    ts  timestamp   NO  MUL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    PRESENCENOTE    varchar(64) YES
```

Some sample data from current query:

```
   ID | Ext   | extID   | TTTS   | TTTM   | TI | TO | MC | TC | DOR       | TOR
    1     7200  35298       5       0.08    1      1  0   1   2017-08-03    2017-08-03 16:19:48
    2     7215  35295       116     1.93    1      1  0   1   2017-08-03    2017-08-03 16:41:32
    3     7218  35302       11      0.18    0      1  0   0   2017-08-03    2017-08-03 16:43:47
    4     7240  35417       79      1.32    1      1  0   1   2017-08-21    2017-08-21 19:13:38
    5     7247  35296       40      0.67    0      1  0   0   2017-08-03    2017-08-03 16:55:50
    6     7255  34935       65      1.08    1      1  0   1   2017-08-21    2017-08-21 18:57:07
    7     7276  35299       146     2.43    1      1  0   1   2017-08-21    2017-08-21 20:37:18
    8     7295  35439       92      1.53    1      1  0   1   2017-08-21    2017-08-21 15:44:36
    9     7306  35283       108     1.8     1      1  1   1   2017-08-03    2017-08-03 21:34:47
    10  7312    35404       54      0.9     1      1  1   1   2017-08-09    2017-08-09 16:56:51
    11  7314    35352       35      0.58    1      1  1   1   2017-08-03    2017-08-03 14:47:33
    12  7330    35297       38      0.63    1      1  0   1   2017-08-03    2017-08-03 16:45:05
```

Expected data should be same format but more than one call per CSR per date. It seems like the upsert may be an issue, but group by could be an issue too.

Now, if I group the above query by only c.extension, I get 15 rows (there are 15 CSRs) and the totals are right but they reflect all 30 days cumulatively, where I need one that has totals for each day in the 30 day interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query (in your question) has these lines in it.

```
 WHERE b.ts BETWEEN curdate() - interval 30 day and curdate()
AND  ...
group by c.extension,b.ts
```

You're grouping by the timestamp. Try using

```
group by c.extension
```

and you may get the result you need.

And, if you want to group by calendar day, use `GROUP BY ... DATE(b.ts)`.

Also note you have a common error on your `WHERE` clause.  `BETWEEN` is generally unsuitable for `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` data, because you get an off-by-one error at the end of the range.

Use this instead.

```
WHERE b.ts >= curdate() - interval 30 day 
  AND b.ts <  curdate()
```

Notice how I used `<` for the end of the date range. This pulls in all the rows with `ts` values up until, *but not including*, midnight today.  On the other hand, `WHERE b.ts BETWEEN .... AND curdate()` pulls in all yesterday's records, and any records from today that happen to lie exactly at midnight.

Both formulations work fine with indexes on the `ts` column.

Comment: I had finally figured part of this out but thank you for officially fixing my issue!